# C Program Strange Characters retrieved due to language setting on Windows

Tags: windows, visual-studio, unicode, msdn

If the below code is compiled with UNICODE as compiler option, the GetComputerNameEx API returns junk characters. 
Whereas if compiled without UNICODE option, the API returns truncated value of the hostname.
This issue is mostly seen with Asia-Pacific languages like Chinese, Japanese, Korean to name a few (i.e., non-English).
Can anyone throw some light on how this issue can be resolved.

```
# define INFO_SIZE 30
int main()
{
    int ret;
    TCHAR infoBuf[INFO_SIZE+1];
    DWORD  bufSize = (INFO_SIZE+1);
    char *buf;

    buf = (char *) malloc(INFO_SIZE+1);

    if (!GetComputerNameEx((COMPUTER_NAME_FORMAT)1,
                                (LPTSTR)infoBuf, &bufSize))
    {
        printf("GetComputerNameEx failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        return -1;
    }

    ret = wcstombs(buf, infoBuf, (INFO_SIZE+1));
    buf[INFO_SIZE] = '\0';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How is `CH_INFO_SIZE` defined?

Comment: My bad! That was a typo.

Comment: You allocate only 30 bytes, regardless of whether you're using "ANSI" (eight-bit chars) or "UNICODE" (16-bit chars).

Answer (score 0):

In the languages you mentioned, most characters are represented by more than one byte. This is because these languages have alphabets of much more than 256 characters. So you may need more than 30 bytes to encode 30 characters.

The usual pattern for calling a function like [`wcstombs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5d7tc9zw.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) goes like this: first get the amount of bytes required, then allocate a buffer, then convert the string.

*(edit: that actually relies on a POSIX extension, which also got implemented on Windows)*

```
size_t size = wcstombs(NULL, infoBuf, 0);
if (size == (size_t) -1) {
    // some character can't be converted
}
char *buf = new char[size + 1];
size = wcstombs(buf, infoBuf, size + 1);
```

Comment: size_t size = wcstombs(NULL, infoBuf, 0);
With this call, wcstombs() returns -1 always since there are no characters written to output buffer.
Can you provide any other suggestions how to overcome this?

Comment: @SeeK That likely means you have a character in your wide string which is outside the current code page.

Comment: @SeeK I also made a mistake with the size parameter, the returned size excludes the null terminator

Comment: Can you elaborate on "That likely means you have a character in your wide string which is outside the current code page" and how I can resolve or find out what is going wrong in there?

Comment: @SeeK Not all characters can be encoded with a given code page. Eg. [code page 1252](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/goglobal/cc305145.aspx) (Latin-1) cannot encode Chinese characters. You have to look up what a function returns in case of an error in the documentation, and check for these values in your code.